ceph orchestrator unavailbale after ceph upgrade
I was trying to issue ceph upgrade from 17 to 18.2.4, as outlined here
ceph orch upgrade start --ceph-version 18.2.4
Initiating upgrade to quay.io/ceph/ceph:v18.2.4

After this, however, the orchestrator no longer responds
ceph orch upgrade status
Error ENOENT: Module not found

Setting the backend back to orchestrator or cephadm fails, because the service appears as 'disabled'. Ceph mgr swears instead that the service is on.
from what I can gather now I'm stuck with one mgr daemon running reef, while the rest of the cluster runs on quincy.
ceph versions
{
    "mon": {
        "ceph version 17.2.7 (b12291d110049b2f35e32e0de30d70e9a4c060d2) quincy (stable)": 5
    },
    "mgr": {
        "ceph version 18.2.4 (e7ad5345525c7aa95470c26863873b581076945d) reef (stable)": 1
    },
    "osd": {
        "ceph version 17.2.7 (b12291d110049b2f35e32e0de30d70e9a4c060d2) quincy (stable)": 31
    },
    "mds": {
        "ceph version 17.2.7 (b12291d110049b2f35e32e0de30d70e9a4c060d2) quincy (stable)": 4
    },
    "overall": {
        "ceph version 17.2.7 (b12291d110049b2f35e32e0de30d70e9a4c060d2) quincy (stable)": 40,
        "ceph version 18.2.4 (e7ad5345525c7aa95470c26863873b581076945d) reef (stable)": 1
    }
}

How do I reinstate the cluster to a healthy state?
EDIT 1
Ceph health:
  cluster:
    id:     16249ca6-4060-11ef-a8a1-7509512e051b
    health: HEALTH_WARN
            insufficient standby MDS daemons available
            mon gpu001 is low on available space
            1/5 mons down, quorum ***
            Degraded data redundancy: 92072087/608856489 objects degraded (15.122%), 97 pgs degraded, 97 pgs undersized
            7 pgs not deep-scrubbed in time

  services:
    mon: 5 daemons, quorum ***
    mgr: cpu01.fcxjpi(active, since 5m)
    mds: 4/4 daemons up
    osd: 34 osds: 31 up (since 45h), 31 in (since 46h); 31 remapped pgs
 
  data:
    volumes: 1/1 healthy
    pools:   4 pools, 193 pgs
    objects: 121.96M objects, 32 TiB
    usage:   36 TiB used, 73 TiB / 108 TiB avail
    pgs:     92072087/608856489 objects degraded (15.122%)
             29422795/608856489 objects misplaced (4.832%)
             97 active+undersized+degraded
             65 active+clean
             31 active+clean+remapped
  io:
    client:   253 KiB/s rd, 51 KiB/s wr, 3 op/s rd, 2 op/s wr

Note: the question was originally asked on SO [https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78949269], i was advised to move it here. I'm currently in the process of searching the MGR logs to investigate the status, and eventually force a downgrade.

What's the health status exactly? Did you try to drain OSDs before the upgrade or something? You could be hit by https://tracker.ceph.com/issues/67329 but I'm not entirely sure.

@eblock no, I didn't touch the OSDs. The cluster was not healthy when I started the upgrade - pasted above - which I guess it's my bad.
I managed to restart the mgr with the previous version, 17.2, but I can't still set the orchestrator as a backend

Never upgrade while the cluster is unhealthy, unless the upgrade is supposed to fix things that break it. Of course, things might fail during an upgrade, but there’s always a risk for that.
Do you have more details like debug logs what the mgr is complaining about? Did it maybe set the global container image to reef and redeployed itself? Can you verify that ceph versions shows Quincy for all daemons? If not, check the „container_image“ config value.

Credits to @eblock that was pointing me to the right direction.
This is indeed related to the bug. https://tracker.ceph.com/issues/67329
I confirmed by looking at the mgr logs, that showed the following:
    debug2024-09-06T10:53:37.389+0000 7fe918b9a700 -1 mgr load Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/cephadm/module.py", line 535, in __init__
    self.to_remove_osds.load_from_store()
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/cephadm/services/osd.py", line 917, in load_from_store
    osd_obj = OSD.from_json(osd, rm_util=self.rm_util)
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/cephadm/services/osd.py", line 782, in from_json
    return cls(**inp)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'original_weight'

I wasn't sure it had to do with anything I did. While looking at config values (ceph config) I did find out the problematic value:
ceph config-key get mgr/cephadm/osd_remove_queue
[{"osd_id": 32, "started": true, "draining": false, "stopped": false, "replace": false, "force": false, "zap": false, "hostname": "cpu03", "original_weight": null, ...}]

this comes from an osd whose removal was still pending on a faulty machine.
Running ceph config-key rm mgr/cephadm/osd_remove_queue, restarting the manager got the cep
